# error: cannot find symbol ... Binding

Tags: kotlin, классы, binding, android-data-binding, build-error

Получил ошибку:

```
D:\User\KotlinAndroidCours\ClothingStore\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\semenovnikolay\clothingstore\databinding\CardItemBindingImpl.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public class CardItemBindingImpl extends CardItemBinding  {
                                         ^
  symbol: class CardItemBinding
```

Выполнил `Invalidate Caches/Invalidate and Restart` не помогло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class CardItemBindingImpl extends CardItemBinding  {

    @Nullable
    private static final androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.IncludedLayouts sIncludes;
    @Nullable
    private static final android.util.SparseIntArray sViewsWithIds;
    static {
        sIncludes = null;
        sViewsWithIds = new android.util.SparseIntArray();
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.imageProductCard, 1);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.nameProductCard, 2);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.priceProductCard, 3);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.currProductCard, 4);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.totalPriceProductCard, 5);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.totalCurrProductCard, 6);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.removeFromCardProductCard, 7);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.sizeText, 8);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.sizeProductInBasket, 9);
    }
    // views
    // variables
    // values
    // listeners
    // Inverse Binding Event Handlers

    public CardItemBindingImpl(@Nullable androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent bindingComponent, @NonNull View root) {
        this(bindingComponent, root, mapBindings(bindingComponent, root, 10, sIncludes, sViewsWithIds));
    }
    private CardItemBindingImpl(androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent bindingComponent, View root, Object[] bindings) {
        super(bindingComponent, root, 0
            , (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView) bindings[0]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[4]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView) bindings[1]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[2]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[3]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton) bindings[7]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[9]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[8]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[6]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[5]
            );
        this.cardProductCard.setTag(null);
        setRootTag(root);
        // listeners
        invalidateAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateAll() {
        synchronized(this) {
                mDirtyFlags = 0x1L;
        }
        requestRebind();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPendingBindings() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (mDirtyFlags != 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setVariable(int variableId, @Nullable Object variable)  {
        boolean variableSet = true;
            return variableSet;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onFieldChange(int localFieldId, Object object, int fieldId) {
        switch (localFieldId) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeBindings() {
        long dirtyFlags = 0;
        synchronized(this) {
            dirtyFlags = mDirtyFlags;
            mDirtyFlags = 0;
        }
        // batch finished
    }
    // Listener Stub Implementations
    // callback impls
    // dirty flag
    private  long mDirtyFlags = 0xffffffffffffffffL;
    /* flag mapping
        flag 0 (0x1L): null
    flag mapping end*/
    //end
}
```

card_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardProductCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:checkable="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageProductCard"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/nameProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageProductCard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/priceProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nameProductCard"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageProductCard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/currProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/ruble"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nameProductCard"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/priceProductCard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/totalPriceProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop = "10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/totalCurrProductCard"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/totalCurrProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop = "10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/ruble"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/removeFromCardProductCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/delete"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backg_button"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sizeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/priceProductCard"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageProductCard"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="size"
                android:src="@drawable/less"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sizeProductInBasket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/priceProductCard"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sizeText"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</layout>
```

Comment: Ну так а есть такой класс-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик, этот класс создаётся автоматически (код и скрины с ошибками я добавил в вопрос)

Comment: он генерируется не просто так, а с вёрстки (`CardItem`), её и добавьте

Comment: @IR42, подскажите, пожалуйста, что, в моём случае с вёрсткой не так (код файла card_item.xml добавил)